# Formatar Data, Hora e Fuso no PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
2019-05-13T10:00:00.000Z
```

E gostaria de transformá-la para este formato: `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'`.

Mas não encontrei em nenhuma documentação qual o formato correto do fuso horário para o formato que eu quero.

```
$dataHoraRetirada = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s', 
    $data['dataHoraRetirada'] )->format('y-m-d\TH:i:s.**???**\Z');
```

> Formato desejato: `y-m-d\TH:i:s.**???**\Z`

Eu poderia simplesmente concatenar com `".000Z"`, mas qual a solução mais correta?

Comment: Eu não sei se você conhece.Tem uma biblioteca php **carbon** com ela e fácil com formatação de data e hora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string `2019-05-13T10:00:00.000Z` representa uma data e hora no formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Para transformar esta string em uma data, você pode passá-la diretamente para o construtor de [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php):

```
$str = "2019-05-13T10:00:00.000Z";
$datetime = new DateTime($str);
```

Com isso você obtém o `DateTime` correspondente. Para transformá-la para outro formato, basta usar [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), passando o formato desejado:

```
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Isso imprime:

> 2019-05-13T10:00:00

---

Se quiser usar `createFromFormat`, basta usar o formato correspondente. De acordo com a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), para a fração de segundos, usa-se `u`, e para o offset (no caso, o `Z` no final, que [indica que a data/hora está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))), usa-se `O` (letra "O" maiúscula):

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', $str);
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

O resultado é o mesmo do código anterior:

> 2019-05-13T10:00:00

---

### Formatação x Parsing

Repare também em outro detalhe:

- [`createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) transforma uma string em uma data (*parsing*). Portanto, o primeiro parâmetro deveria ser **o formato no qual a string está**, mas você estava usando o formato para o qual queria converter (`'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'`).
- [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) faz o oposto: transforma a data em uma string (formatação). Por isso o parâmetro deste método deve ser o formato **para o qual a data será convertida** (aqui sim deve ser `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'`). Mas você estava tentando usar o formato no qual a string original está.

---

#### Outros formatos para o offset

O `Z` no final [indica que a data/hora está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)).

Mas existem outros valores possíveis para offsets, como `+01:00` ou `-03:00`. E de acordo com a ISO8601, o offset "1 hora depois de UTC" [pode ser representado de 3 maneiras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC): `+01:00`, `+0100` (sem os dois pontos) ou `+01`.

Felizmente, o código acima também funciona para estes formatos:

```
// todos retornam a mesma data
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', "2019-05-13T10:00:00.000+01:00");
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', "2019-05-13T10:00:00.000+0100");
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', "2019-05-13T10:00:00.000+01");
$d = new DateTime("2019-05-13T10:00:00.000+01:00");
$d = new DateTime("2019-05-13T10:00:00.000+0100");
$d = new DateTime("2019-05-13T10:00:00.000+01");
```

---

**Obs**: existem alguns [formatos pré-definidos, descritos na documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.synopsis), mas eles não funcionaram.

Por exemplo, até existe a constante [`DateTime::ISO8601`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.iso8601), mas ela não considera a fração de segundo.
Por sinal, a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.iso8601) diz que `DateTime::ISO8601` "*não é compatível com a norma ISO 8601, mas continua existindo por razões de retro-compatibilidade*", e recomenda que se use [`DateTime::ATOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.atom) (mas esta constante também não leva em conta as frações de segundo).

A que mais se aproxima do formato em questão é [`DateTime::DATE_RFC3339_EXTENDED`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.rfc3339_extended) (*a partir do PHP 7.0.0*), que considera as frações de segundo, mas ela também não funcionou (aparentemente, [ela só funciona para formatar, mas não para *parsing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48949373)).

[Veja aqui a tentativa de usar estas constantes](https://ideone.com/hUZZtv), e note que todas falham (a única que funciona é a solução proposta no início desta resposta, usando o formato `'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO'`).

---

A [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) ainda cita que podem ser usados `P` ou `T` para o offset (em vez do `O`). Para o *parsing*, não parece haver diferença:

```
$str = "2019-05-13T10:00:00.000Z";
// todos criam a mesma data
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO', $str);
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uP', $str);
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uT', $str);
```

A diferença entre esses formatos se dá na hora de formatar a data:

```
// usando data em UTC
$d = new DateTime("2019-05-13T10:00:00.000Z");
echo $d->format('O, P, T') . "\n";
// usando offset -03:00
$d = new DateTime("2019-05-13T10:00:00.000-03:00");
echo $d->format('O, P, T') . "\n";
```

No caso, a saída é:

> +0000, +00:00, Z
>   -0300, -03:00, GMT-0300

Ou seja, `O` formata o offset para `HHMM` (horas e minutos, sem os dois pontos), `P` formata usando os dois pontos, e `T` formata para o que a documentação chama de "timezone abreviation" - no caso, o resultado foi `Z` para UTC e `GMT-0300` para o offset -03:00, mas alguns timezones usam nomes como PST (Pacific Standard Time, usado na costa oeste dos EUA).

De qualquer forma, estes formatos se comportam de maneira diferente apenas na formatação. Mas para o *parsing*, [todos funcionaram para as strings em questão](https://ideone.com/pFD2Se).

Answer (score 2):

A tua pergunta não está clara o suficiente, mas penso que queres formatar para um dado fuso horário, se for isso experimente usar desta forma.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

?>
```

Vai dar isto:

> 2000-01-01 00:00:00+12:00

Comment: Eu recebo a string 2019-05-13T10:00:00.000Z e quero transforma-la para este formato 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s' e utilizar a função estática DateTime::createFromFormat, sendo que o primeiro parâmetro é o formato do parâmetro dataHora que a classe DateTime está recebendo. Ou seja, eu gostaria de saber qual é o formato do  "2019-05-13T10:00:00.000Z"

Por isso coloquei os "???", pois são estes caracteres que não sei qual letra asrepresentaria. Ficou mais claro? Não quero transformar nenhum fuso horário.