# Qual o formato desta hora?

Tags: php, datetime

Qual o formato desta data e hora em PHP 7.2?

```
2019-05-13T10:00:00.000Z
```

Por exemplo, a data hora `2019-01-01 10:00:00` tem o formato `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Comment: Por favor, não polua a comunidade com perguntas repetidas. Se já perguntou, tenha paciência que cedo ou tarde alguém responderá. Se em dois dias ninguém responder, há a opção de [oferecer recompensa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2621/5878) pela resposta. Se tem pressa para resolver o problema, talvez o site não seja o melhor lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Bom a pergunta ficou meio confusa, caso queria formatar essa data utilize a pergunta já respondida: [Formatar Data, Hora e Fuso no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/356361/formatar-data-hora-e-fuso-no-php).

Mas caso gostaria de saber o formato desta data, você poderia dar uma olhada na documentação do PHP 7 sobre `DateTime`.

```
DateTime implements DateTimeInterface {

       const string DateTimeInterface::ATOM = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::COOKIE = "l, d-M-Y H:i:s T" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::ISO8601 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sO" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::RFC822 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::RFC850 = "l, d-M-y H:i:s T" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::RFC1036 = "D, d M y H:i:s O" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::RFC1123 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::RFC2822 = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::RFC3339 = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::RFC3339_EXTENDED = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s.vP" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::RSS = "D, d M Y H:i:s O" ;
       const string DateTimeInterface::W3C = "Y-m-d\TH:i:sP" ;
```

O trecho acima é referente a classe `DateTime`, para mais detalhes veja os seguintes tópicos.

- [Classe DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [Exemplos de Datas](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php#datetime.constants.rfc2822)

Talvez o seu seja um desses: **DATE_ATOM** | **DATE_ISO8601** | **DATE_RFC3339_EXTENDED** | **DATE_W3C**, mas eu não tenho certeza, de qualquer forma espero ter ajudado :).

Comment: Esse formato (`2019-05-13T10:00:00.000Z`) é definido pela [**norma ISO 8601**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Só que a constante `DateTime::ISO8601` não considera a fração de segundo. A que mais se aproxima do formato em questão é `DATE_RFC3339_EXTENDED`, mas sei lá pq ela não funciona, [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/hUZZtv). Uma maneira de resolver é o que sugeri em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/356609/112052